# PySpark: groupby() count('*') not working as expected, or I'm misunderstanding

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to get

1. row of things within categories
2. row of all things within categories

Below is what I've tried.

```
# This is PySpark
# df has variables 'id' 'category' 'thing'
# 'category' one : many 'id'
#
# sample data:
# id    | category | thing
# alpha |        A |     X
# alpha |        A |     X
# alpha |        A |     Y
# beta  |        A |     X
# beta  |        A |     Z
# beta  |        A |     Z
# gamma |        B |     X
# gamma |        B |     Y
# gamma |        B |     Z

df_count_per_category = df.\
    select('category', 'thing').\
    groupby('category', 'thing').\
    agg(F.count('*').alias('thing_count'))

# Proposition total, to join with df_turnover_segmented
df_total = df.\
    select('category').\
    groupby('category').\
    agg(F.count('*').alias('thing_total'))

df_merge = df.\
    join(df_count_per_category,\
        (df_count_per_category.thing== df_count_per_category.thing) & \
        (df_count_per_category.category== df_count_per_category.category), \
    'inner').\
    drop(df_count_per_category.thing).\
    drop(df_count_per_category.category).\
    join(df_total,\
        (df.category== df_total.category), \
    'inner').\
    drop(df_total.category)

df_rate = df_merge.\
    withColumn('thing_rate', F.round(F.col('thing_count') / F.col('thing_total'), 3))
```

I'm expecting `thing_count`, `thing_total`, and `thing_rate` to be the same for same `thing` since each `thing` is `category` exclusive. However, although `thing_count` is same value across rows, `thing_rate` is not. Why is that?

This is the R equivalent I would like to achieve:

```
# This is R
library(tidytable)
df_total = df |>
  mutate(.by = c(category, thing),
         thing_count = n()) |>
  mutate(.by = category,
         thing_total = n()) |>
  mutate(thing_rate = thing_count / thing_total)
```

This is the expected result (+/- some columns):

```
# This is a table
category | thing | thing_count | thing_total | thing_rate
       A |     X |           3 |           6 |        0,5
       A |     Y |           1 |           6 |     0,1667
       A |     Z |           2 |           6 |     0,3333
       B |     X |           1 |           3 |     0,3333
       B |     Y |           1 |           3 |     0,3333
       B |     Z |           1 |           3 |     0,3333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 2nd `join` is not what you intend to do.

You are referencing the original `df` in the 2nd join condition which resulting in creating a wrong association. Instead, you want to join the `df_total` to the result of the first join.

```
df_merge = df.\
    join(df_count_per_category ,\
        (df.thing== df_count_per_category.thing) & \
        (df.category== df_count_per_category.category), \
    'inner').\
    drop(df_count_per_category .thing).\
    drop(df_count_per_category .category)

df_merge = df_merge.join(df_total ,\
        (df_merge.category== df_total.category), \  # Reference df_merge.category.
    'inner').\
    drop(df_total.category)
```

Alternatively, you can achieve your expected dataframe with window functions without multiple joins.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (df.select('category', 'thing',
                F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('category', 'thing')).alias('thing_count'),
                F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('category')).alias('thing_total'))
      .withColumn('thing_rate', F.round(F.col('thing_count') / F.col('thing_total'), 3)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a much more elegant solution!